# Windows shell - prevent load or dynamically reload

Tags: registry, windows-shell

We have a dedicated program that run on windows, but we want this program to be the first screen when the user starts up the machine. I removed the `explorer.exe` string from the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

However, when a privileged user wants to get access to the "normal windows interface", we run the `explorer.exe`, but the normal shell won't come up - instead, only a simple folder windows opens...

How do we reload the windows shell (start menu, task bar, etc...) ?
Or - is there another way to accomplish this task ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explorer checks that Winlogon value to see if it is the default shell so you have to set the shell value to explorer.exe, start explorer, wait a second or two and then restore the original value.